# How to set Skype for Business meeting settings/policies via UCWA

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, ucwa

I already created a working online meeting via ucwa. Now i want to change the settings which are present in the default skype addin.
It is possible to change the presenter (via automaticLeaderAssignment) and lobby options (via accessLevel and lobbyBypassForPhoneUsers). **What about the following participation options?**

- Disable IM
- Mute all attendees
- Block attendees' video

The documentation seem to be missing reference to these settings.

Resources:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-options-for-Lync-Meetings-f628a0fe-6b94-469b-975c-8852a19bddad
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/myonlinemeetings_ref

**Edit 1:**

Ok i am a step further. I was able to receive the proerties set by the skype addin via outlook spy:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<Settings Version="14.0">
<Public>false
</Public>
<ConferenceID>P33PBHWF
</ConferenceID>
<HttpJoinLink>https://meet.ucteam.de/cde/P33PBHWF
</HttpJoinLink>
<ConfJoinLink>conf:sip:cde@ucteam.de;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:P33PBHWF?conversation-id=hOrq7N6A3Dou
</ConfJoinLink>
<Subject>test
</Subject>
<ExpiryDate>2/27/2017 5:30:00 PM
</ExpiryDate>
<AutoPromote OrganizerOnly="false" Value="Company"/>
<BodyLanguage>0407
</BodyLanguage>
<Participants>
    <Presenters/>
    <Attendees>
        <User name="ABC" smtp="abc@ucteam.de" sip=""/>
    </Attendees>
</Participants>
<Permissions>
    <AdmissionType>ucAnonymous
    </AdmissionType>
</Permissions>
<MeetingOwner Smtp="cde@ucteam.de" Sip="cde@ucteam.de"/>
<IMDisabled>true
</IMDisabled>
<AudioMuteEnabled>true
</AudioMuteEnabled>
<VideoMuteEnabled>true
</VideoMuteEnabled>
<Audio Type="none" AudioModalityEnabled="true"/>
```

Important are the last 3 XML nodes. But it is possible to set them via ucwa? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Just to give you another option here: We are using remote powershell injections.

Comment: @BastianW : And what exactly do you achive with remote powershell? Changing the settings on the users device or on the server? Are you using a webservice? What is your usecase?